# "Delegates page is not available" in Outlook 2010 with Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook, outlook-2010

I have a user that is trying to assign delegates but receives the following error message when they try to access Delegate information in Outlook 2010:

> The delegates page is not available.  Cannot access Outlook folder.

I've found this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2753709 but having performed the steps in the workaround, the string `CN=Deleted Objects` does not appear in the `.ldf` file generated (nor even the word `Deleted`).

I'm not sure what to attempt at this point.  If I create a profile on my PC with his mailbox, the same issue occurs so it's not Outlook or his PC I'm pretty sure...

Comment: If they have rules, try exporting all of their rules. then run `outlook /cleanrules` from the outlook.exe directory and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Ah, this did it.  Thanks!  Can you add this as a solution so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they have rules, try exporting all of their rules. then run outlook /cleanrules from the outlook.exe directory and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: This has just worked for me with accounts fork-lifted from Exchange 2013 / Outlook 2013 to Exchange Online/Office 365 with Outlook 2016.